# how can i display parsed xml data in UItableview?

Tags: xml, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray

1. I have become able to parse the xml url using `TBXML` parser.
2. parsed data will be into a `NSMutableArray` named `records`.
3. Here is the code....

   ```
   if ([[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"order"]) {
       NSLog(@"xml element checking");
       TBXMLElement *id = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"id" parentElement:element];
       TBXMLElement *status = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"status" parentElement:element];
       TBXMLElement *date = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"date" parentElement:element];
       TBXMLElement *by = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"by" parentElement:element];
       TBXMLElement *total = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"total" parentElement:element];


       [records addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [TBXML textForElement:id],
                           [TBXML textForElement:status],
                           [TBXML textForElement:date],
                           [TBXML textForElement:by],
                           [TBXML textForElement:total],nil]];
   ```
4. Now these `records` data will be display in the tableview cell,so number of rows will be as same as `records` array size.
5. now in my `tableview` there is five `UILabel`.every label will display the attribute value of the `records` array value.

   6.i can display the value of the attribute first time until scroll the tableview but my problem is when i start scrolling in my `UITableview` then value starts to display in wrong cell.
6. Here the tableview code...

   ```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
   cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
   cell.accessoryView = imageView;
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

   cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,8,290, 120)] autorelease];
   cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   cellView.tag =10;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

   imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 40, 48, 48)];
   imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"productbox.png"];
   imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
   imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
   imgView.tag = 5;
   [cellView addSubview:imgView];

   CGRect idLabelRect = CGRectMake(65, 0, 190, 18);
   idLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:idLabelRect] autorelease];
   idLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   idLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   idLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   idLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   idLabel.tag = 0;

   CGRect statusRect = CGRectMake(65, 22, 190, 22);
   statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRect] autorelease];
   statusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   statusLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   statusLabel.tag = 1;

   CGRect orderDateRect = CGRectMake(65, 48, 190, 22);
   orderDate = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:orderDateRect] autorelease];
   orderDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   orderDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   orderDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   orderDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
   orderDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   orderDate.tag = 2;

   CGRect byRect = CGRectMake(65, 75, 190, 22);
   byLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:byRect] autorelease];
   byLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   byLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   byLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   byLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
   byLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   byLabel.tag = 3;

   CGRect totalRect = CGRectMake(65, 98, 190, 22);
   totalLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:totalRect] autorelease];
   totalLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
   totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   totalLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
   totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
   totalLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   totalLabel.tag = 4;

   [cellView addSubview:idLabel];
   [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
   [cellView addSubview:orderDate];
   [cellView addSubview:byLabel];
   [cellView addSubview:totalLabel];
   }
     x = [records count];
     //NSLog(@" total number of row: %d",x);
       if(y<x){
   if(y == indexPath.section){
       cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
       idLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:0];
       statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];
       orderDate = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:2];
       byLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:3];
       totalLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:4];
       imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];

       NSLog(@"the value of y: %d",y);
       NSLog(@"the value of indexpath.section: %d",indexPath.section);
       idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:0]];
       statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:1]];
       orderDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:2]];
       byLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:3]];
       totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:y] objectAtIndex:4]];
       y++;
   }
   }
   return cell;
    }
   ```

   Thats mean first time when table loads then value are displaying in right cell but when i start scrolling value are not displaying right cell.

Last couple of days i am being fade up with this problem so please anybody know what is solution then inform me as soon as possible...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How you add parsed data into MutableArray ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have got my answer it was very silly problem......may be it will helpful for someone...

Here is the code...i have just change the tableview delegate...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;

    cellView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,8,290, 120)] autorelease];
    cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cellView.tag =10;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellView];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 40, 48, 48)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"productbox.png"];
    imgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    imgView.tag = 5;
    [cellView addSubview:imgView];

    CGRect idLabelRect = CGRectMake(65, 0, 190, 18);
    idLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:idLabelRect] autorelease];
    idLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    idLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    idLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    idLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    idLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    idLabel.tag = 0;

    CGRect statusRect = CGRectMake(65, 22, 190, 22);
    statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:statusRect] autorelease];
    statusLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    statusLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    statusLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    statusLabel.tag = 1;

    CGRect orderDateRect = CGRectMake(65, 48, 190, 22);
    orderDate = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:orderDateRect] autorelease];
    orderDate.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    orderDate.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    orderDate.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    orderDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    orderDate.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    orderDate.tag = 2;

    CGRect byRect = CGRectMake(65, 75, 190, 22);
    byLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:byRect] autorelease];
    byLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    byLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    byLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    byLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    byLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    byLabel.tag = 3;

    CGRect totalRect = CGRectMake(65, 98, 190, 22);
    totalLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:totalRect] autorelease];
    totalLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    totalLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    totalLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    totalLabel.tag = 4;

    [cellView addSubview:idLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:statusLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:orderDate];
    [cellView addSubview:byLabel];
    [cellView addSubview:totalLabel];
}


cellView = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
idLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:0];
statusLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:1];
orderDate = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:2];
byLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:3];
totalLabel = (UILabel *)[cellView viewWithTag:4];
imgView = (UIImageView *)[cellView viewWithTag:5];

    //here is my changed of code
    idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:0]];
    statusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Status: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:1]];
    orderDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:2]];
    byLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:3]];
    totalLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:4]];
```